# Is the Nvidia GT 120 a step up from the 8800 GT?

Tags: mac, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

The video card on my [Mac Pro (early 2008)](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp11) died. I had a NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT 512MB in my machine.  Apple has the [Nvidia GT 120](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC002ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) for sale on there site.  The comments on the previous link seem to indicate this will work on a Early 2008 Mac Pro even though it is listed for an Early 2009 Mac Pro.  My question is this:

Is the Nvidia GT 120 a step up from the 8800 GT.  I haven't followed video cards in a while and have lost track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GT 120 is [about the same as a 9500GT](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/259548-33-nvidia%C2-geforce-gt120), which itself is a huge step **down** from the 8800GT.

Comment: To add a little more context to @Sathya's response: Many of the lower end nVidia cards of the newer generation are actually have worse overall performance than high-end cards of the previous generation. 8800GT/8800GTX vs 9400GT/9500GT is one such example.